# MySQL Hanging Up and Refusing to Answer

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I have a script (FiveM) doing server side SQL queries, but sometimes the same queries just return an error for ECONNREFUSED, even tho nothing changes meanwhile (seemingly) and the queries are the same which run most of the time, these ones get connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 totally random

By inspecting the log it says:
"Aborted Connection to DB: Got an error reading communication packets"

If this helps, After some time the server is running (couple minutes) if I try to access the db by the SSH, it says it cannot bind a socket and will not let me do mariadb or mysql command.

Comment: Sounds to me like an issue with your network connection. *Got an error reading communications packets* is pretty clearly a networking issue. So is *cannot bind a socket* from SSH.

Comment: it can be a network error even if the script is querying localhost? i dont get it

Maybe i worded it in a wrong way, ssh it's only my point of view, the issue comes from a script on the machine(server) querying the localhost mysql